# Get Values With One Select and Bind To View Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, web-services, viewmodel

I am using a web service to get an active directory user and bind his values to view model. But web service is so slow, so each query takes time one by one. Can i get values with just one query and bind them to view model?

My code is like this:

```
    public ActionResult EditUser(string id)
    {
        AdVM model = new AdVM();

        Security s = new Security();
        s.Cn = "Users";
        ADLogin a = new ADLogin();

        model.Username = a.ADGetAllUser(s).Where(x => x.UserName == id).Select(x=>x.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
        model.DisplayName = a.ADGetAllUser(s).Where(x => x.UserName == id).Select(x => x.DisplayName).FirstOrDefault();
        model.FirstName = a.ADGetAllUser(s).Where(x => x.UserName == id).Select(x => x.FirstName).FirstOrDefault();
        model.LastName = a.ADGetAllUser(s).Where(x => x.UserName == id).Select(x => x.LastName).FirstOrDefault();

        model.Title = a.ADGetAllUser(s).Where(x => x.UserName == id).Select(x => x.Title).FirstOrDefault();
        model.Department = a.ADGetAllUser(s).Where(x => x.UserName == id).Select(x => x.Department).FirstOrDefault();
        model.Division = a.ADGetAllUser(s).Where(x => x.UserName == id).Select(x => x.Division).FirstOrDefault();

        return PartialView("_PartialEdit", model);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
AdVM model = a.ADGetAllUser(s).Where(x => x.UserName == id).Select(x=> new AdVM() {Username = x.UserName, DisplayName = x.DisplayName... other fileds}).SingleOrDefult();
```

Comment: That's what i was looking for. Just SingleOrDefult didn't work. I used FirstOrDefault.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var user = a.ADGetAllUser(s).Where(x => x.UserName == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Just remove the Select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, hitting AD is not the fastest thing.  I would cache the users off to static variable and refresh it every so often.  Then you could just retrieve the individual user needed for the GET.

Alternatively, you could change your method to return them all at once as suggested by Florim.  You wouldn't need the id parameter in the method and would need to rework your view most likely.

Comment: I'm calling the web service from home, right now. I guess this is the reason of it's slow speed. At work it's ok.